# Getting the key to the maximum component of a tuple in a dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, max

I have a dictionary whose components are all 2-tuples (all integers) and I want to find the key to the tuple with the largest second component. How can I do this in Python 2.6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will do it (where `d` is your dictionary):

```
max(d.items(), key=lambda(k,v):v[1])[0]
```

In this solution, the key (if you pardon the pun) is to use the optional `key` argument to `max`.

Comment: can you explain what the k and v is? how would I do this if they were 3-tuples but I still wanted to maximize on the second?

Comment: @Double AA: `k` and `v` are the key and the value of the dictionary entry, so `v` gets assigned the entire tuple. The exact same code will  work if the dict contains 3-tuples and you want to maximize on the second component.

Answer (score 2):

aix' answer is a good one. You can achieve the same without using lambdas if you prefer, though:

```
import operator
m = max(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```